# Xcode Swift can not receive notification from Object-C

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter

I use NetworkSpeedMonitor to check user networking 
this is my code

```
networking = NetworkSpeedMonitor()
networking.start()
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(networkSpeedChanged(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: NetworkDownloadSpeedNotificationKey), object: self)
```

this is my selector function

```
@objc func networkSpeedChanged(_ notification:NSNotification) {
    // never run
    if let downloadSpeed = notification.userInfo?[NetworkSpeedNotificationKey] as? String {
        self.networkingLabel.text = downloadSpeed
    }    
}
```

but I find that the selector is not run

Answer (score 0):

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(networkSpeedChanged(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: NetworkDownloadSpeedNotificationKey), object: nil)

instead of

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(networkSpeedChanged(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: NetworkDownloadSpeedNotificationKey), object: self)